# How to switch on SelectMode in IdeaVim?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, intellij-plugin, ideavim

Let's say I have this text file:

```
export const DEFECT_GROUP_REST_URL = "defectGroup";
export const DEFECT_GROUP_PAGE_SEARCH_URL = `${DEFECT_GROUP_REST_URL}/query/`;
export const DEFECT_GROUP_DELETE = `${DEFECT_GROUP_REST_URL}/delete`;
export const DEFECT_GROUP_SAVE = `${DEFECT_GROUP_REST_URL}/save`;
```

I want to change `DEFECT` word with `VEHICLE`.

I searched for the target word: `/DEFECT`

Now I want to change matches text with `cgn` command. But it didn't work.
But as far as I understand IdeaVim do not switch on SelectMode with `g` command. How can I change the visually selected text in IdeaVim? Like [cgn](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#gn) command in real `Vim`.

Comment: `gn` commands are supported in the latest version of IdeaVim. Which version do you have?

Comment: IdeaVim -> Version: 0.50; My Intellij Version is: 2018.2.4, I checked the Plugin repo and lastes version was 0.50 I think I have to update my IDE.

Comment: Yes, `gn` commands are supported since 0.52. And this version is incompatible with IDEA versions < 2018.3.

Comment: `gn` command comes with Vim 7.4 which is released on August 10 2013, and I download my IdeVim at 2018 that means IdeaVim do not run a real vim instance at the background. Do they implement all Vim features manually?

Comment: That's correct. Vim emulator emulates vim commands and doesn't use original vim in any way.

Comment: I updated my IDE and reinstall IdeaVim and `gn` command works. Thanks for your time.